# Angular Material sidenav issues

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I am developing with angular an admin, and resources I'm using Angular Material sidenav.

I could make the menu work 50%, can not do the toggle function normally.

Test case, click several times on the toggle menu it opens :D

```
    <header class="nav-header">
        <a ng-href="#/" class="docs-logo">

            <h1 class="docs-logotype md-heading">Angular Material</h1>
        </a>
    </header>

    <ul class="skip-links">
      <li class="md-whiteframe-z2">
        <md-button ng-click="focusMainContent($event)" href="#">Skip to content</md-button>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <md-content flex role="navigation">
        <ul class="docs-menu">

            <li ng-repeat="sectionmenu in menu.sections" class="parent-list-item {{sectionmenu.className || ''}}" ng-class="{'parentActive' : isSectionSelected(sectionmenu)}">

                <h2 class="menu-heading md-subhead" ng-if="sectionmenu.type === 'heading'" id="heading_{{ sectionmenu.title | nospace }}">
                    {{sectionmenu.title}}
                </h2>

                <menu-link sectionmenu="sectionmenu" ng-if="sectionmenu.type === 'link'"></menu-link>
               <menu-toggle sectionmenu="sectionmenu" ng-if="sectionmenu.type === 'toggle'"></menu-toggle>

            </li>

        </ul>

    </md-content>

</md-sidenav>
```

Follows a problem Plunker:

http://embed.plnkr.co/fq3tonZoddSSZkyAaWD8/preview

Editable Plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/FQcZrwYlh4LPKuje9mLI?p=preview

**UPDATED and RESOLVED:**

In template menu-toggle.tpl.html, change this:

```
<ul ng-show="isOpen()" id="menu-{{sectionmenu.title | nospace}}" class="menu-toggle-list">
    <li ng-repeat="page in sectionmenu.pages">
        <menu-link sectionmenu="page"></menu-link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

for this:

```
<ul id="menu-{{sectionmenu.title | nospace}}" class="menu-toggle-list">
    <li ng-repeat="page in sectionmenu.pages">
        <menu-link sectionmenu="page"></menu-link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't see anything wrong. More details?

Comment: toggle menu does not work, only from time to time .. For you worked usual?

Comment: It's broken for me too on Chromium 43. Triple click works consistently.

Comment: Lots of issues for side-nav: https://github.com/angular/material/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=sidenav

Comment: I think mine is a very silly mistake because everything is working.

I read any errors, none like mine ..'ve checked and checked the git, but did not get anything yet.